# Threadlocal usage in callbacks

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I was reading about ThreadLocal class when I came across the below statement by Joshua Bloch multiple times..

“Sleazing” values through callbacks that you don’t control: sometimes you must call a library method that calls back into your package. At this point, you need some context that you were unable to pass to yourself, due to deficiencies in the library. In this rare situation, thread locals can be a lifesaver.

Having a hard time understanding this one..Would appreciate if someone could elaborate and explain

Thanks..Heena

Comment: I think your question title is not a good fit. Try to change it to specify your question.

Comment: Thread local var is a sort of a "static" value that is static only within a context of given thread so you can set it in whatever method you want, and then read the value in whatever other method but within the same execution-flow.

Comment: @ivanovic Done..Hope it fits now.

Comment: @fatfredyy I am sorry but how does it relate to the statement I am trying to understand.

Comment: threadlocal is a local variable defined to every thread , in some scenarios we need the threads to carry some information , well , threadlocal is the answer to that , consider it a local variable to every thread which can be only accesses by the owner thread

Comment: And +1 to Mr. Bloch for coining the term "sleazing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My application calls a library that searches stored data.

That library also has an interface you can implement that tells it how to convert the raw results of a search into the data format that you want.

My implementation of how to convert search results into the objects I want, involves knowing a particular time zone.

So the process is, (A) I call library search method, (B) search method then calls my other piece of code that converts raw results into my format, (C) my conversion requires knowing a timezone.  The challenge is how do I make information, the timezone, that I know at point A, available at point C?

Obviously the methods that the library offers don't include passing around a time zone, so I stick it in a ThreadLocal!

Comment: So the deficiency that your library has is that it does not include passing of timezone which your overall flow needs at (C) and the context that you need for yourself is the Threadlocal holding the timezone.. So it means that ThreadLocal objects facilitate/hold information which are meant to be available to other parts of the application..Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I wouldn't really call it a deficiency in most cases where it happens.  If every framework that provided extension points provided extra method arguments for passing around arbitrary application data at different levels of context for the once in an occassional while that you need it... those would be some nasty APIs ;)

Comment: There are also times where it comes up inside frameworks where things are being triggered by annotation processors, so there aren't many practical ways to provide runtime information.  (Looking at you JAXB.)

Comment: Agree :) But considering the leaks that ThreadLocal variables can dangerously cause(read about the Tomcat container scenario)..do we have a better alternative for this situation

Comment: I think people are overly paranoid based on that one old article that guy at IBM wrote about how their web container was crappy at thread management and worded it like it was some universal truth.  That's might just be me though :)

Answer (score 1):

Say you call into a third-party function which later on calls back into your code. In your callback you need some context, i.e. to be able to access some variables of your. However, the third-party function is deficient in that it provides no way of passing an object reference through their code into your callback.

What are you to do?

Unfortunately, you don't really have much choice other than to store the context in what is effectively a global variable (oh horror!). `ThreadLocal` is a slight refinement of the global variable in that multiple threads using this hack won't step onto each other's toes.

Of course, if the callback happens on a different thread than the one calling the third-party function, this technique breaks down.

Also, this technique doesn't scale. If you simultaneously register two callbacks, you'll need two different callback functions and two different global contexts.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the problem with callbacks on different threads.  Not providing a context pointer for use in callbacks is just stupid - you may have no idea which thread will execute the callback because tasks are queued to a pool.